# Regarding PDB usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

Its always recommended to store the PDB files for each public build so that we can debug if there is any issue on Production server.

My doubt is if my source code is changed even due to addition of two lines whether i will be able to debug when i run the program and try to attach it to my debugger?
In my understanding since PDB contains the line no. and local variable only,if the source code is changed we can't debug , so how its helpful unless we go back to original source which created the dll but if we know the source file then why we need the original pdb since we can replace it our local pdb.
I am sure i am missing something here..Will be glad if you clear this.

Comment: what source control solution are you using? visual studio can actually go into source control and get the appropriate version.

Comment: If you want to debug with PDB then yes, you should keep the PDB. If you are keeping the exe then it's trivially easy to keep the PDB too.

Answer (score 2):

When using a [symbol server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a [source server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should be able to debug binaries (or a dump from a customer) without requiring access to the source that produced the modules and symbols.  It is tremendously helpful.

We update both servers for every build, which allows us to debug an application in a QA environment even if we do not have the source code on disk.

PDB files on their own isn't too helpful if the source that produced them is missing.